# Recursive print all documents inside a directory

Tags: bash, netbeans

I wanna print all my source code from a directory with a bash script, but I'm not able to find good commands to do it. I made a deep search around the net, but I didn't find anything useful.

This bash script will be executed with cron, every day.

Someone can help me, please?

Comment: What have you tried already? There are plenty of people here willing to help, but nobody is going to help you if you don't put forth any effort yourself. Use this site as a tool to enhance your learning, don't depend on people to write code for you.

Comment: What are you trying to print; the names of the source files, or the content of the files?

Comment: @Dear Keith, I would have already solved if I was able to do it! I made a deep research on the net, without finding anything useful.

Comment: @Mike: thank you, I'm trying to print the content

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
find . -type f -exec lpr {} \;
```

This assumes that you want to print all of the files in the current directory `.` or any of its subdirectories. If you need to limit the command to certain types of files, use `-name` or `-iname`.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a simple script that takes names from a text file and prints them at certain intervals. You could query the contents of the print folder to get the document names, put them in a text file and then loop through the text file with a wait in between until all documents are printed.

Pseudo Code would look something like this.

```
Populate Text File Function ()  
{  
  Set Folder Path  
  Get Document Names in folder  
  Write Document Names to Text File  
}  
Print Function  
{  
  While Not End of File{  
  Get Document Name  
  Print Document Name  
  Move down 1 line  
      Wait a timed interval  
 }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you take a look at [`dirent.h`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/dirent.h.html). By using the functions defined in `dirent.h` you should be able to achieve your goal.